# Align EditTexts next to TextView

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout, android-edittext

I want my EditTexts to be aligned above each other, be equally long, and aligned to the right. 
I'm using Linear Layout.
Right now [it looks like this](http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/5/13100230869-orig.jpg).

Here's my Android Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:configChanges = "orientation"
    android:screenOrientation = "portrait" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Mail:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tbopmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fornavn:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tbopfornavn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Efternavn:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tbopefternavn"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Adresse:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tbopadr"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Telefon:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />





        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tboptlf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="8" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btopret"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Opret mig som bruger!" android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" android:layout_marginRight="1dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use weightSum in LinearLayout ...

Comment: if query has been resolved please vote/accept any answer found close to your answer to finish this story and make stack Clear for all.... :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `android:layout_weight` attribute, which tells the Activity the percentage of a parent each view should take up.  Each parent view considers this attribute when laying its children out, the parent layout has a weight of "1" to assign to each of its views.  This corresponds to 100% of the view.  If you give the children (your textviews and edittexts) `android:layout_weight=".5"`, they will each expand to take up 50% of the parent's space.  For your case, it seems like you may want something like a weight of .25 for your text views and .75 for your edit texts.

Additionally, if you don't like working with decimals, you can assign your parent view the `android:weightSum` attribute.  Your new number will correspond to 100% of the parent view, instead of 1.  For example, if you wanted a 25%-75% split for your views, give each parent LinearLayout a weightSum of 4, the TextViews a weight of 1, and the EditTexts a weight of 3.

I just looked at your code before submitting and realized that you already use the `layout_weight` attribute.  To get a little more in depth, when you give a single view in a parent a weight of 1, as you are, you're telling it to take up all available space after the other views have been laid out.  So your textview is wrapping it's content and taking up a minimal amount of the parent, and the EditTexts get the rest.  Basically, weight will not prevent a view from being laid out.  If it requires more space in a parent than the weight is providing it, the remaining space is divided based on the weight of the other children.

Answer (score 0):

i don't try but maybe you can use table layout for that problem.
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html 
can take a look to this link

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a RelativeLayout

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

or otherwise try a TableLayout with equal colums

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add **android:orientation="vertical"** to your linearlayout1,2,3...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```